How to make ListBox or ListView items checkable with proper keyboard support and accessibility
In C# WPF application, I want to create a simmple interactive list with checkable items and proper keyboard navigation and screen reader accessibility. I have the following requirements:

For the actual interactive list implementation, I can use either ListView or ListBox control, or whatever control satisfies the below requirements.
I need to achieve proper behavior if user navigates the list using keyboard:

I want the whole list to be a single Tab stop. That is, When focus is placed on a control before the list, then Tab key press moves focus to the list, and second Tab key press moves focus out of the list.
When focus is in the list, pressing Up or Down arrow key navigates only among list items which can be checked or unchecked via spacebar.


I need to achieve proper screen reader narration when navigating the list. When focus is on a list item,the following should be narrated by screen reader:

Whether the selected item is checked or not.
The position of the selected item in the list and total list size, e.g. "Banana, 2 of 3, not checked".



I first tried the following simple XAML:
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="Apple" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="Banana" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="Orange" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>

But the problem is that first Tab key press focuses the currently selected list item itself only, and second Tab key press focuses the checkbox only. I need it to be just single Tab stop.
I therefore tried the following modification which I've found at another stackoverflow question:
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Control">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="Apple" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="Banana" />
    </ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>
        <CheckBox Content="Orange" />
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>

The problems with this modified solution are the following:

The JAWS screen reader narrates the item text twice, e.g. "Banana, Banana, not checked, checkbox".
The JAWS screen reader narrates the item position and total number of items for items always as "1 of 1", no matter which item is currently selected an how many items the list consists of.

Please, how can I make the list behave properly?
